# Incorrect sorting according en_US.UTF-8

Tags: sort, unicode, i18n

I'm seeing a weird behavior of the sort command when I sort by en_US.UTF-8.

I'm trying to sort this file (LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort testdata):

> 㐀
>
> 㐃㐄
>
> ▼▽◢
>
> ㎏㎜㎝
>
> ｂｑｚ
>
> ㄠㄨㄩ─┃┆
>
> ◆□■△
>
> ぁあぃい
>
> ┻╋┠┯┨
>
> ꓃꓄꓆꒺꒻
>
> 々—～‖…‘”
>
> 龷龸龹龺龻
>
> ⺁⺄⺈⺋⺌⺗⺧⺪⺮⺳⺶⺷⺻⻊
>
> mario
>
> david
>
> 且
>
> 丁
>
> 㐀丁
>
> 㐂
>
> 㐀且
>
> 嗄
>
> 阿

What happens is that the "mario" and "david" strings are sorted in the correct order, but the other characters are left in place. I would expect to see "david", "mario" and after them all the other strings.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect English strings to necessarily be positioned before all other strings after sorting. I'd rather expect that strings are first sorted by language order ("david" before "mario") and then either by Unicode code point number ("programmer's sort", corresponding to `LC_ALL=C`) *or* simply left in place (since the other strings are not English).

From `man sort` I gather that the file `/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE` *should* contain the sort sequence, but that file is not on my system even though it's an English installation. (`/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE` is my only collation file.)

Comment: I would expect the same order. Btw the locale for English is /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US that loads /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common in the LC_COLLATE section.